# Taking a nap at Puy du Fou

Tags: france, sleeping, amusement-parks

I am traveling to [Puy du Fou](http://www.puydufou.com/en/) , I am wondering whether there is any good place to take a nap in this theme park.

Comment: @pnuts ideally a free place to go and close to the shows. Indeed just for one hour or so.

Comment: What means of transportation will you have? Car, bike, or just your feet?

Comment: @Gilles foot or car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are benches at several places in the park, some in quiet areas a bit away from the shows and attractions, e.g. near a small lake under some trees. These could be nice for a small nap. There might also be some grass available (not sure if you were authorized to step on the grass though).

If you're looking for something more comfy, there are several B&B's around the park, some even within walking distance (10-15 min walk so a few minutes' drive). You can [spot them using Google Maps](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Puy+du+Fou/@46.8881608,-0.9290884,1572m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m6!1m3!3m2!1s0x48065eb9615fe2ab:0x48386616c38da263!2sPuy+du+Fou!3m1!1s0x48065eb9615fe2ab:0x48386616c38da263!6m1!1e1) to have a idea of how far they are.